# Ansible recursive loop in role's default variables

Tags: variables, ansible

How can I reuse variables in other variables in *Ansible* (2.1.x) without causing recursive loops?

## Setup

Consider this `roles/<role>/defaults/main.yml` file:

```
---
liquibase:
  version: "3.5.3"
  download_file: "liquibase-{{liquibase.version}}-bin.tar.gz"

  # I also tried this alternative with a similar result:
  # download_file: "liquibase-{{liquibase[version]}}-bin.tar.gz
...
```

and this `roles/<role>/tasks/main.yml` file:

```
---
- name: Liquibase | Download
  debug:
    msg: "download_file: {{liquibase.download_file}}"
...
```

## Error

I'd expect the variable `liquibase.download_file` to have the value `liquibase-3.5.3-bin.tar.gz` but when I run a playbook using this role, I get the following error:

```
...
TASK [liquibase : Liquibase | Download] *******************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "...: recursive loop detected in template string: liquibase-{{liquibase.version}}-bin.tar.gz"}
...
```

## My Use Case

Obviously I want to download [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) and I want to let the role's user decide which version to use. I also want to give the possibility to completely override the download location (file, URL, etc.), e.g. for using a company's FTP server or similar.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Referencing other dict keys in the same parent dict is not supported. See this [issue](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/8603).

You can only refactor your variables to make `version` and `download_file` in different variables trees, like:

```
liquibase_version: "3.5.3"
liquibase_download_file: "liquibase-{{liquibase_version}}-bin.tar.gz"
```

P.S. if this your role's defaults, separating `liquibase_version` into standalone variable make even more sence. This way user would have to redefine only `liquibase_version` and `liquibase_download_file` will get the changes; while in case of dict (as in your question), you can't override only one key, user whould have to set full dict with `version` and `download_file` keys.

Comment: This is a correct regarding the question posed, however the PS is inaccurate: The user can configure Ansible's `hash_behaviour` to `merge`, ([See the docs here](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_configuration.html#hash-behaviour))

Comment: Good remark, but changing `hash_behaviour` is not recommended in general, so you should not write roles that require this setting (keeping in mind that you write roles to be reusable across playbooks).

Answer (score 4):

I found this frustrating when trying to blend the elegance of YAML structures with the flexibility of Jinja2. As it isn't supported, one way around it (which I admit is something of a kludge) is to introduce a pseudo-private section to help break the cycle. First we declare anything that might cause a dependency:

```
# Pseudo private KV pairs, used to work around recursion issues.
_liquibase_version: "3.5.3"
```

We only have to declare anything that would be declared within the dictionary and forms a dependency for another dictionary key. Next we can declare the dictionary as we wanted but use the 'private' key value pairs where necessary:

```
liquibase:
  version: "{{_liquibase_version}}"
  download_file: "liquibase-{{_liquibase_version}}-bin.tar.gz"
```

Of course, `_liquibase_version` is not *really* private, but acts as a helper so we only have to define the value once but still get the benefit of being able to refer to `{{liquibase.version}}` and `{{liquibase.download_file}}` later on.